# Downloading objects from S3 with presigned URL

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm using java [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) to get objects.

Given a presigned URL that looks like this:

> https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.pdf?Signature=xxx&Expires=1234&AccessKeyId=xxx

Can I use AmazonS3Client to get the object? Can't seem to find any documentation for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the pre-signed URL, it's probably easiest to just make a normal HTTP request for it.